# What is different QKeyEvent modifiers in Qt4 and Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, modifier, qkeyevent

When I enter the number pad side of the keyboard in qt4, I want to receive QEvent::KeyPress and process it.
However, if I check the modifiers() of the event, KeypadModifier should come in, but NoModifier is entered in the first time.
After that, get a proper KeypadModifier.
In qt5, the keypadModifier is obtained from the beginning.
Why is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with qt4 itself.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15833?gerritIssueStatus=Open

So, I use KeyRelase event.